# How to convert dictionary to schema in FastAPI

Tags: python, schema, fastapi, pydantic

The below schema can be converted to dict using `branch.__dict__`

```
branch = BranchIn(name='jfslkjf', regionId='fdfasd')
```

```
branchDict = branch.__dict__
branchDict = {'name': 'jfslkjf', 'regionId': 'fdfasd' }
```

How can i convert the dict object to schema again in FastAPI

Comment: What do you mean by converting dict to schema.

Comment: Reverse of the above operation...

Answer (score 2):

You can simply spread the dict back into the `Branch`.

```py
branchDict = {'name': 'jfslkjf', 'regionId': 'fdfasd' }
branchObj = Branch(**branchDict)
```

Fastapi uses pydantic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use double asterisk **`**`** for unpacking the multiple variables to turn to a **single** object

```
class Branch(BaseModel):
    name: str
    regionID: str


def check_type(obj):
    return f"{obj}  \n  type: {type(obj)}"
```

I created this class and type checker, then i created the branch object

```
branch = Branch(name='jfslkjf', regionID='fdfasd')
check_type(branch)

Out: name='jfslkjf' regionID='fdfasd'  
     type: <class '__main__.Branch'>
```

Then i converted to a dict

```
branch_dict = branch.__dict__
check_type(branch_dict)


Out: {'name': 'jfslkjf', 'regionID': 'fdfasd'}  
     type: <class 'dict'>
```

So on i used double asteriks to unpack it

```
test_branch = Branch(**branch_dict)
check_type(test_branch)

Out: name='jfslkjf' regionID='fdfasd'  
     type: <class '__main__.Branch'>
```